# Issues with a for loop and xcopy creating folders that mimic the file names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting, xcopy

I am trying to copy a set of files to a new location that I have listed out in a file list (filelist.txt) by using a for loop and xcopy command. However, there is an issue with my script where a directory with an identical file name is being created.

So for instance, I have the following within filelist.txt

```
MC\1807\1807-06-10\M-1807-00246071.tif
BC\1825\18250218\B-1825-00000012-0.tif
BC\1837\18370727\B-1837-00000013-0.tif
MC\1848\1848-08-04\M-1848-00000007.tif
MC\1849\1849-02-24\M-1849-00000008.tif
```

The command line execution looks like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (filelist.txt) do echo D|xcopy "E:\files\%i" "F:\files\%i" /i /z /y
```

Notice I am copying from E to F drives. So on E, the files are stored as such:

```
E:\files\MC\1807\1807-06-10\M-1807-00246071.tif
E:\files\BC\1825\18250218\B-1825-00000012-0.tif
E:\files\BC\1837\18370727\B-1837-00000013-0.tif
E:\files\MC\1848\1848-08-04\M-1848-00000007.tif
E:\files\MC\1849\1849-02-24\M-1849-00000008.tif
```

After I run the xcopy command, I receive this result set:

```
F:\files\MC\1807\1807-06-10\M-1849-00000008.tif\M-1807-00246071.tif
F:\files\BC\1825\18250218\M-1849-00000008.tif\B-1825-00000012-0.tif
F:\files\BC\1837\18370727\M-1849-00000008.tif\B-1837-00000013-0.tif
F:\files\MC\1848\1848-08-04\M-1849-00000008.tif\M-1848-00000007.tif
F:\files\MC\1849\1849-02-24\M-1849-00000008.tif\M-1849-00000008.tif
```

Notice how it created a folder with the files names and *then* placed the file within that folder instead of a direct copy from the source directory to the destination directory.

What is it within my xcopy command that could cause for this?

Comment: `xcopy "E:\files\%i" "F:\%~pnxi"` or something alike. Read `for /?` for explanation of `~` (tilde) modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When doing the copy, it prompts you whether it is a Directory (D) or a File (F). On my echo, I was returning D:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (filelist.txt) do echo D|xcopy "E:\files\%i" "F:\files\%i" /i /z /y
```

By changing it to echo F, this has been resolved.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (filelist.txt) do echo F|xcopy "E:\files\%i" "F:\files\%i" /i /z /y
```